# Adding results of a 'select' statement on to a table I'm building from several other tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL. I have a query that returns a timestamp in a set format for every row in a table. The query is:

'''

```
select to_char(create_ts, 'HH24:MI:SS') from 
SCHEMA.TABLE
```

'''

I also have a table I am building by taking columns from other tables and using inner join to match them based on shared columns & data. I now need to add the above timestamp logic to this table in the same manner i.e. bring the resulting timestamp in only for rows which match. The code for the table I am building so far is:

'''

```
select A.*,
A.TRANSACTION_ID,
B.AMOUNT,
B.CHARGE_ID,
C.CHARGE_TYPE_ID,
D.CHARGE_GROUP,
E.EXCHANGE_ID,
E.TRADE_DATE
FROM SCHEMA.ESTIMATES A
left join SCHEMA.CHARGES B
ON A.ESTIMATE_ID = B.ESTIMATE_ID
left join SCHEMA.IRECHARGES C
ON B.CHARGE_ID = C.CHARGE_ID
left join SCHEMA.chargetypes D
ON C.CHARGE_TYPE_ID = D.CHARGE_TYPE_ID
left join SCHEMA.TRADE_TRANSACTIONS E
ON A.TRANSACTION_ID = E.TRANS_ID
```

'''

I am not able to just add another line above in the same manner as I have been such as "F.select to_char(create_ts, 'HH24:MI:SS') from SCHEMA.TABLE"

Any ideas?

Comment: are you getting any errors? if yes, can you post the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a `Subquery`
Which is using a query inside another query.
Use a JOIN with a SELECT.

Does this solve your problem ?

```
SELECT
    A.*,
    A.TRANSACTION_ID,
    B.AMOUNT,
    B.CHARGE_ID,
    C.CHARGE_TYPE_ID,
    D.CHARGE_GROUP,
    E.EXCHANGE_ID,
    E.TRADE_DATE,
    timestamp_table.timeformated

FROM SCHEMA.ESTIMATES A
LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.CHARGES B ON (A.ESTIMATE_ID = B.ESTIMATE_ID)
LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.IRECHARGES C ON (B.CHARGE_ID = C.CHARGE_ID)
LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.chargetypes D ON (C.CHARGE_TYPE_ID = D.CHARGE_TYPE_ID)
LEFT JOIN SCHEMA.TRADE_TRANSACTIONS E ON (A.TRANSACTION_ID = E.TRANS_ID)

LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT to_char(create_ts, 'HH24:MI:SS') as timeformated, matchID
    FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
) as timestamp_table ON (A.matchID = timestamp_table.matchID)
```

*NB: it is easier to work with well indented code*

Comment: If it worked, why didn't you accept the answer, @paddyusa?

Comment: @Littlefoot accepted there. I have a new question pertaining to this same overall query however. Is there a way to filter the result of the time query to only bring in rows where the time is after 7am and before 6pm??

Comment: Have a look in "BETWEEN" key word. https://sql.sh/cours/where/between

Maybe look into other basic SQL statements.  For your example I would INNER join with the `subquery` and in the subquery I would add a `WHERE` clause. In which you filter on dates

Comment: yea got it sorted with a where statement - tks